# How to move commit to master from another branch

Tags: git, git-commit

I have master branch and a developer branch. I did some work on developer branch, and now i want to commit my final work (final project) to master branch. How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard:

```
git checkout master
git merge develop

# if there are merge conflicts, resolve them and follow with:
# git commit
```

That will transfer all of the historical commits on `develop` to `master`.  If you want to keep `master`'s commit history clean, you can squash it all into one commit:

```
git checkout master
git merge develop --squash
# resolve any merge conflicts
git commit
```

Comment: what if from developer branch I don;t want to merge the latest push on master? On my computer I do have the final project. but meanwhile someone else did a push, which i don t want to merge on master?

Comment: Let me just confirm what you are asking: your **local** develop branch is what you want to merge into master, but not anything that your coworker pushed to the **remote** develop branch?

Comment: The examples I used only use/modify your local branches, so this shouldn't be an issue for you.  If you *wanted to* merge the **remote** develop branch into master instead, you would do `git merge origin/develop`.